# Data Frame modification based on existing columns in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, aggregation

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

```
col1       | col2  | col3
--------------------------------
2021-04-23 | 30.22 | 2021-04-01
2022-11-15 | 15.50 | 2022-05-22
2022-10-01 | 48.96 | 2022-11-14
```

And based on 3 columns above I need as a result something like below:

- col1_X - show only year and month from "col1" and month like 01, 02 and so on presetn as 1, 2 and so on
- col2_X - round values from "col2", round up from value 5 after dot
- col3_X - Modify format of presented date from for example "2021-04-01" to "01-Dec-21" (I prefer solution included dictionary like 01 is January and so on...)

  | col1 | col1_X | col2 | col2_X | col3 | col3_X |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 2021-04-23 | 2021-4 | 30.22 | 30 | 2021-04-01 | 01-April-21 |
  | 2022-11-15 | 2022-11 | 15.50 | 16 | 2022-05-22 | 22-May-22 |
  | 2022-10-01 | 2022-10 | 48.96 | 49 | 2022-11-14 | 14-November-22 |

How to do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try, suppose df your dataframe:

```
df['col1_X'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1']).dt.to_period('M')
df['col2_X'] = df['col2'].round(0).astype(int)
df['col3_X'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col3']).dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
# Here to rearrange the index
df = df[['col1','col1_X','col2','col2_X','col3','col3_X']]
df
```

[image]